# Pygame works with two of my .wav files but when adding one .wav it crashes?

Tags: python

I am new to programming, and this is my first time trying to make a game.  I have two sound effects so far.  One plays whenever my ship fires, and it works fine, the other plays a sound when all the enemies are destroyed.

I am trying to play a .wav file every time an enemy ship comes into contact with mine.  I am using the same method to load/play these sounds but for whatever reason it crashes unexpectedly.  The .wav file making it crash isn't longer than the others.

Here is what I have just for the sound portion.

```
pygame.init()
destroy = pygame.mixer.Sound('explosion.wav')
fires = pygame.mixer.Sound('laser.wav')
hit = pygame.mixer.Sound('oops.wav')
```

Later in my lines of code I call the sounds using something like this:

```
soundname.play(0, 0)
```

Why would it work fine with the first two sounds but not the third one (the hit sound)?  They are all .wav files and all about the same length.

Comment: Any chance that your third file is a compressed .wav?  Pygame apparently doesn't support them.

Comment: Good question, but just looking at it it doesn't appear so.  Tomorrow I am going to try a different .wav file and see if maybe it's just something with the particular file.

Comment: Something like this would likely be a problem with the audio file, not the code.